# How can I get "x" objects before a given object?

Tags: ruby, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

It's better to explain this in pseudo-code, I want to do this:

```
limit_object = Model.first(id: bla)
objects = Model.all(constraint: limit_object, limit: 30)
```

If the objects are:

```
[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

and `limit_object` is 'c', it should return:

```
[a, b, c]
```

Is there a way to do this in DataMapper?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found it:

```
quotes = Model.all(:for_date.lte => date, limit: 10)
```